# Issue in sending encoded parameters on servlet

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

I am using this class for encoding/decoding:

```
public class enc_dec {
public static Cipher dcipher, ecipher;

 public  enc_dec() {

          byte[] salt = { (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
                       (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03 };

          int iterationCount = 19;
try {
                 // Generate a temporary key. In practice, you would save this key
                 // Encrypting with DES Using a Pass Phrase
                 KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec("".toCharArray(), salt,iterationCount);
                 SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES")
                              .generateSecret(keySpec);

                 ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
                 dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

                 // Prepare the parameters to the cipthers
                 AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt,
                              iterationCount);

                 ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
                 dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

          } catch (Exception e) { }
    }

   // Encrpt Password
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public String encrypt(String str) {
          try {
                 // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
                 byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
                 // Encrypt
                 byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
                 // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
                 return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          return null;
   }

   // Decrpt password
   // To decrypt the encryted password
   public String decrypt(String str) {
          Cipher dcipher = null;
          try {
                 byte[] salt = { (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
                              (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03 };
                 int iterationCount = 19;
                 try {
                       String passPhrase = "";
                       KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(),
                                     salt, iterationCount);
                       SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory
                                     .getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES")
                                     .generateSecret(keySpec);
                       dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
                       // Prepare the parameters to the cipthers
                       AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt,
                                     iterationCount);
                       dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
                 } catch (Exception e) {}


                 // Decode base64 to get bytes
                 byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
                 // Decrypt
                 byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
                 // Decode using utf-8
                 return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          return null;
    }
```

This is my URL-which i am sending from a JSP page:

```
http://localhost:8080/Sample_Project/send_encode.ENC?type=M0z7jTCb8PPfSZxfAdhw3Q==&payment=UxCU5BdZh4U=&sr_no=eN1X3XOeYuI=
```

This is my send_encode servlet:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
         HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
 if(session.getAttribute("session_set")!=null)
 {
 classes.enc_dec enc=new classes.enc_dec();
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
  PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
  String type=enc.decrypt(request.getParameter("type"));
  String payment=enc.decrypt(request.getParameter("payment"));
  long sr_no=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("sr_no"));
  try{
  RequestDispatcher comprd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/new_page.jsp?type="+enc.encrypt(type)+"&payment="+enc.encrypt(payment)+"");
  comprd.include(request, response);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println("The ecxeption is "+e);
  }
  }
```

The exception I am facing is:

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[send_encode]: Servlet.service() for servlet send_encode threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "eN1X3XOeYuI="
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
at controller.send_encode.doGet(send_encode.java:30)
```

I have set encoding as UTF-8 but still i am getting the exception.I have also tried other questions posted on SO but unable to get any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your stack trace shows that the exception is thrown by a call to Long.parseLong() in send_encode.doGet(). The code you posted has no such instruction. Show us the real, appropriate code. Also, respect the Java naming conventions. And don't assume that bytes generated by an cipher are valid UTFD8 characters. They're not. Use base-64 or Hex encoding to transform the byte array to printable characters.